# How to show print dialog from javascript without getting "Page Unresponsive" warnings?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've got a page with a simple "print" image/link that executes a simple javascript `onclick` handler. I'm finding that Chrome will complain about the page with a "Page Unresponsive" warning when I take too long to inspect the print dialog. I do not see this behavior in other browsers.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a onclick="if(window.print) window.print(); return false;">
  <img src="print-button.png" alt="[Print]" />
</a>
```

There are no other active scripts on the page, so I'm guessing that this `onclick` handler is the problem. My *guess* is that Chrome does something like this behind the scenes:

1. Accept click event from OS
2. See `onclick` handler exists
3. Start stopwatch
4. Invoke `onclick` handler
5. `onclick` handler calls `window.print()` (which blocks, waiting for user input)
6. [time passes]
7. Stopwatch indicates that too much time has passed
8. Chrome issues a warning to the user

I would consider this a bug in Chrome, if true, since the `window.print` call shouldn't be "timed". That is, it's a blocking user-interactive action and the user is allowed to take as much time as they need.

I've tried cheating by doing this:

```
<a onclick="if(window.print) setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 0); return false;">
  <img src="print-button.png" alt="[Print]" />
</a>
```

... but it does not change anything -- Chrome still complains about the long-running script.

Am I using the wrong technique to trigger the print dialog? Or is this a bug in Chrome?

I am running v72.0.3626.119 on 64-bit Mac and I *cannot reproduce this* while  I have a client running the same version in 64-bit Windows and she is reporting this issue.

Comment: What version of chrome are you on?

Comment: Your return false should be immediately after the window.print() call.

Comment: @Olian04 I have updated the question with version information. I apologize for not providing it initially.

Comment: @Luis I'm not sure I understand. I *am* immediately returning `false` after the `window.print()` call.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known bug in Chrome since Feb 27 2018 / Chrome 64

There is a fix slated for Chrome 73

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=816869

Comment: Thanks for this; I hopeful that this is the issue and I'll accept this answer once Chrome 73 is out and the client can confirm it.